# Mysql Insert Values Error

Tags: php, mysql

So I am working with a very old site where the client wont let me upgrade it to any sort of PDO. Anyway I have to use mysql querys and its really starting to depress me. I cant seem to get this to work:

```
$array = array('1' => 1, '2' => 2);

$values = "({$array['1']}, 2, 'data3', 4, 5)";

if ($moreData){
    $values = $values.", ({$array['6']}, 7, 'data8', 9, 10)";
}

$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_reward ".
                 "('field1','field2','field3','field4','field5') ".
                 "VALUES ".$values);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

Here Is The Error Message:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''field1','field2','field3','field4','field5') VALUES (1, 2, 'data3' at line 1<br />Error No: 1064<br />INSERT INTO table ('field1','field2','field3','field4','field5') VALUES (1, 2, 'data3', 4, 5)
```

Comment: Echo out the SQL you're generating and run it in the database, and see what the error message is.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary He hasn't got PDO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field names in your query should not be within single quotes.  They either need to have no quotes or be inside back-ticks.

You also need to make sure the field types match the data types as you are trying to enter in some integer values.